# How can I know that user change the dir string and sort string?

Tags: extjs

this is my code

```
    var store = {
        user_store: new Ext.data.Store({       
            autoLoad: false,
            proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
                url: a/b/c
            }),
            remoteSort: true, 
            baseParams: {
                dir: 'ASC',
                sort: defaultSort,
                start:0, 
                limit:pagesize
            },
            reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({

                totalProperty: 'total',
                root: 'root', 
                fields:['fullname', 'first']
            })
        }),
    };
```

I can use "store.user_store.getSortState().direction" and "store.user_store.getSortState().field" to get dir string and sort string. 
But I can't know. When did user change the dir string and sort string.

I try to solve my question.
this is my code

```
                             var dir =defaultDir;
                             if((store.user_store.getSortState().direction))
                             {
                                dir =store.user_store.getSortState().direction;
                             }

                             var sort =defaultSort
                             if((store.user_store.getSortState().field))
                             {
                                sort =store.user_store.getSortState().field;
                             }
```

But the windows say: TypeError:store.user_store.getSortState() is undefined. How can I do?

(PS:Sorry,my English is not very well.  my extjs is v3.4)

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/3-4/#!/api/Ext.data.Store-cfg-sortInfo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
                             var dir =CDS.defaultDir;
                             var sort =CDS.defaultSort
                             var state =store.user_store.getSortState();
                             if(state)
                             {
                                dir =state.direction;
                                sort =state.field;
                             }
```

Answer (score 0):

can you use directly like this without defining a variable again.

```
var user_store= new Ext.data.Store({       
        autoLoad: false,
        proxy: new Ext.data.HttpProxy({
            url: a/b/c
        }),
        remoteSort: true, 
        baseParams: {
            dir: 'ASC',
            sort: defaultSort,
            start:0, 
            limit:pagesize
        },
        reader: new Ext.data.JsonReader({

            totalProperty: 'total',
            root: 'root', 
            fields:['fullname', 'first']
        }),
        })

    }),
};
```